# How to receive List of object in android from Server using signalR

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

My android code is:

```
mHubProxy.on( "PushContentsToClient", new SubscriptionHandler1<ChatMessageResponsePOCO[]>() {
            @Override
            public void run(final ChatMessageResponsePOCO[] msgs) {
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d("MGR_ERROR",""+msgs.length);
                        }
                    });
                }

        }, ChatMessageResponsePOCO[].class);
```

And My Class:

```
public class ChatMessageResponsePOCO {
    public long ChatId;
    public int ChatAck;
    public String MobileNumber;
    public String ChatContent;
    public Date ChatDatetime;
    public int MessageType;

}
```

Server side code is:

Clients.Client(connectionToken).PushContentsToClient(chatMessageResponseListDTO);

Server side Entity :

```
 public class ChatMessageResponsePOCO
    {
        public Int64 ChatId { get; set; }
        public int ChatAck { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string ChatContent { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChatDatetime { get; set; }
        public int MessageType { get; set; }
    }
```

Its work fine for String but getting no response for `List<ChatMessageResponsePOCO>`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

ChatMessageResponsePOCO this in not an array. This is a class. So Do something like this

```
mHubProxy.on( "PushContentsToClient", new SubscriptionHandler1<ChatMessageResponsePOCO>() {
        @Override
        public void run(final ChatMessageResponsePOCO msgs) {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("Mobile No ","" + msgs.MobileNumber); //Example
                        Log.d("MGR_ERROR",""+msgs.length);
                    }
                });
            }

    }, ChatMessageResponsePOCO.class);
```

Comment: Thanks But i am sending List from server using `Clients.Client(connectionToken).PushContentsToClient(chatMessageResponseListDTO) ` where chatMessageResponseListDTO list of chatMessageResponsePOCO.